# How to get quantile of object array

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have an object array, called `dataArray`, where one object is like this:

```
{
   id,
   x,
   y
}
```

now I want to have the lower quantile of this array by using d3. I thought about something like this:

```
quartile = d3.quantile(dataArray, 0.25, function(d) {return d.y})
```

but unfortunately there is no accessor option for this method. How can I get the quantile of a property from an object array ? Thanks in advance

Comment: did you try  to use the jquery labery ?

Comment: @MarcosBrinner jquery will be an option too. cann you provide a simple example how to achieve this ?

Comment: sorry i  was readding  quantity

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the solution to my problem. I need to get an array of only a certain property of an array of objects, so I don't need an accessor within the quantile method.

```
// get an array of just the y property values
var keyArray = dataArray.map(function(item) { return item["y"]; });

// calculate a lower quantile of this array
var quantile_y = d3.quantile(keyArray, 0.25);
```

**UPDATE:**

In order to work correctly, the array given to `d3.quantile()` has to be sorted. e.g.

```
keyArray.sort(d3.ascending);
```